# MIPS instruction sll for array

Tags: assembly, mips

Trying to understand how to do `t0 = A[j-1]` in MIPs by looking at an example of `t1=A[j]` 
Details

```
1. j is $s2, initialized to 5  
2. i is $s1  
3. Array is $s0
```

I have the example 
`t1=A[j]`

MIPS

```
sll $t3, $s2, 2 //I don't really understand why we need to do a left shift of 2 
add $t5, $s0, $t3 
lw $1, 0($t5)
```

I referenced to another stackoverflow post which stated

> So the instruction sll $t0, $s0, 2 is multiplying $s0 by 4 (2^2) and
>   writing back to $t0.

But i do not see any multiplication for `t0 = A[j]`

Comment: As the quote you posted states, `sll $t0, $s0, 2` is doing the multiplication. Shifting left by N bits is the same (more or less) as multiplying by 2^N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory in your MIPS machine is addressable by bytes, i.e. there is one byte (8 bits) of memory at address 0, one at address 1, etc.. Whole "word" on MIPS machine consist of four bytes (32 bits). So you can interpret bytes at addresses 0 to 3 as single word. And then you can interpret also bytes at addresses 1 to 4, 2 to 5, ... 4 to 7 as single words, but all of them except the last 4..7 option are partially overlapping with 0..3 bytes.

So to store array of words (32 bit integers) in memory, where each element of array has independent value, not affected by other elements, you need 4*N bytes of memory at least.

Your `A` is pointing at address of first byte of first element in the array. then A+1, A+2 and A+3 addresses are still pointing at following bytes of the first element. The A+4 address is address of first byte of second element.

The C language has built-in "pointer math", where expression like `*(A+2)` is identical to `A[2]`, because the C compiler will check the type of the pointer, and multiply the "2" by the size of single element.

But in assembly you have to do this yourself, i.e. in byte array the address of `A[j]` is simple `adr = A + j`, but for word array with each element occupying four bytes the correct address calculation is `adr = A + j*4`.

The shift left by two bits is, thanks to the way how binary encoding of integer works, identical to multiplying the number by value 4.

so the `sll $t3, $s2, 2` is actually `t3 = j * 4`, which is later added to `A` address, and the final value is used as address to load word from.

Similarly to access `A[j-1]` (in C syntax) in MIPS assembly you have to calculate the raw memory address as `adr = A + j*4 - 4` (or `adr = A + (j-1)*4`, whichever is simpler to implement ... actually *usually* in these kinds of loops you don't calculate the pointer every time, but keep the previous pointer value, and just do +-4 to it to move to next/previous element in memory, without multiplication/shifting).